# L1B Visa question

Tags: usa, working-visas

My L1B and petition expired on 10 Sept 2013, but I had valid I94 through Jan 2016. I have stayed in the US for 2 year 6 months.

Due to a family emergency, I had to fly back to India on Oct 4th. I left my all household goods, car, etc, at my home in the US. I am now physically in India.

The company I work for has filed a for a new L1B visa on my behalf. My visa interview date is scheduled for 2 Nov 2014.

My green card application is under process on EB2 (currently it is on labor clearance).

What is the possibility of getting a new L1B visa? What are some questions the Consulate might ask, apart from my special knowledge?

Comment: There's a range of questions they might ask. Could you be specific about what you're wondering?